# Trying to pull user ID from database given username, what's wrong with this MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

`$username` is the, well, username of the logged in user.

```
$username_query = mysql_query("SELECT userid from registerusers WHERE username = '$username'");
$username_id = mysql_fetch_row($username_query);
```

I'm trying to use `$username_id` in another query and am testing by printing out in a page, and it always returns 'Array'. I'm really bad with MySQL and most of the research I've done has yielded overcomplicated responses and I'd just like to get a response specific to my problem so I really understand this, so I'm sorry if this is deemed a 'bad' question.

Comment: try a `print_r($username_id)` to know what is inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_*()` functions return an array or object, representing the entire ROW of data you've fetched, even if that row consists of a single value.

Your user id value will actually be `$username_id[0]`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Just out of curiosity, is this considered "best practice" or is there some other function that would allow me to pull the individual value?

Comment: There's DB libraries that have shortcut functions for fetching a single value from a result set directly, but not the standard mysql_*() functions. So yeah, this is best practice, only because it's the ONLY practice. I'd suggest switching to using a better variable name, such as `$result` for the fetch call. You can then do `$user_id = $result[0]`; to make it explicitly clear afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$username_id[0]` in the other query.